# Correcting indexes of one list according to another

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have 2 lists that consists of string and blanks,in list1 indexes of blank values are true,but in list2 all blank values are slided to the end of list.How should I correct indexes of values in list2 like in list1?

`list1 = ['a','','b','c','','','z','','k'], list2 = ['d','q','j','m','n','','','','']`

Expected output :  `['d','','q','j','','','m','','n']`

i tried everything that i found on google but none of worked.Thats one of the methods i tried,but didnt worked.

```
for i, val in enumerate(list1):
   if val != '':
      index = list2.index(val)
      newlist2[i] = val
      newlist2[index] = list2[index] `
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this code work, we assume the lists are correctly defined. If there are more not null elements in `list1` than in `list2`, this code would raise an exception.

```
list1 = ['a','','b','c','','','z','','k']
list2 = ['d','q','j','m','n','','','','']
# Create an iterable with all the valid values in list2
non_null_elements = (i for i in list2 if i)
# If element in list1 is not null, take the next valid element in list2,
# blanck otherwise
list3 = [next(non_null_elements) if i else ''
         for i in list1]
```

I think this approach is much more readable than other answers that suggest to iterate `list2` by using an index.

---

To write explicitly what [B Remmelzwaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17200348) suggested.
If you are sure there are not empty strings in any other position in `list2` that the tail, you can use this version:

```
list2_iterable = iter(list2)
list3 = [next(list2_iterable) if i else ''
         for i in list1]
```

Comment: I would suggest just using `iter(list2)`, because the padded empty strings would make raising an exception less likely.

Comment: Indeed, but that would be a less flexible idea as it would stop working if `list2` had an empty string in other possition.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by keeping a counter and iterating over `list1`:

```py
list1 = ['a','','b','c','','','z','','k']
list2 = ['d','q','j','m','n','','','','']

list3 = []

i = 0
for x in list1:
    if x:
        list3.append(list2[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        list3.append(x)

print(list3)
```

Output:

```py
['d', '', 'q', 'j', '', '', 'm', '', 'n']
```

For fun I made it a list comprehension, but I wouldn't recommend using it:

```py
i = -1
list3 = [list2[i := i+1] if x else x for x in list1]
```

And even more confusing with iterators (but without ternary):

```py
iter2 = iter(list2)
list3 = [x and next(iter2) for x in list1]
```